# Are there any syntax errors in this case statement? Language = SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, case, alias, boolean-expression

```
case ('monthcharge' <> 0)
WHEN TRUE THEN 'monthcharge' * datediff(mm,, 'start', 'stop')
WHEN FALSE THEN case ('weekcharge' <>0)
                    WHEN TRUE THEN 'weekcharge' * datediff(ww, 'start', 'stop')
                    WHEN FALSE THEN 'daycharge' * datediff(dd, 'start', 'stop') 
                    ELSE 0
                    END
ELSE 0
END 'final_total'
```

Data types:

```
alias       | datatype
daycharge   | float
weekcharge  | float
monthcharge | float
start       | datetime
stop        | datetime
```

Comment: comparing strings to numbers does not make sense.

Comment: When you run it on SQL Server, does it say there are any syntax errors? This seems like a pretty easy to answer question.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. And did you get any errors when you ran the query? if yes, then yes, if no, then no.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are putting your column names in quotes -- you want to take those quotes out.

Also you have to choices for your tests -- no need to case statements like that if you only are going to use two choices.

Here is the fixed code.

```
case WHEN monthcharge <> 0.0 TRUE THEN monthcharge * datediff(mm,, 'start', 'stop')
     ELSE case WHEN weekcharge <> 0.0 THEN weekcharge * datediff(ww, 'start', 'stop')
               ELSE daycharge * datediff(dd, 'start', 'stop') 
          END
END AS final_total
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *single quotes* for string constants. In case you have keywords as object names then use should use *square brackets* to escape them

Here is better version of what you are trying to do

```
SELECT final_total = CASE 
                       WHEN monthcharge <> 0 THEN monthcharge * Datediff(mm, [start], [stop]) 
                       WHEN weekcharge <> 0 THEN weekcharge * Datediff(ww, [start], [stop]) 
                       WHEN daycharge <> 0 THEN daycharge * Datediff(dd, [start], [stop]) 
                       ELSE 0 
                     END
```